# How to use cache in cakephp

Tags: php, cakephp, caching

I have a site in cakephp and I have configure cache for It.
In bootstrap.php I have write this line like the guide in the site of cakephp:

```
Cache::config('default', array('engine' => 'File'));

Cache::config('short', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 hours',
    'path' => CACHE,
    'prefix' => 'cake_short_'
));

// long
Cache::config('long', array(
    'engine' => 'File',
    'duration' => '+1 week',
    'probability' => 100,
    'path' => CACHE . 'long' . DS,
));
```

In my controller I want to cache some query that are call many times like this:

```
class User extends AppModel {

    public function get($alias) {
        $result = Cache::read('get_users', 'longterm');
        if (!$result) {
            $result = $this->find('all', array('conditions' =>array( 'alias' => $alias)));
            Cache::write('get_users', $result, 'longterm');
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```

I want to know if is efficient to cache query with parameters (alias) or is better to cache only query with not parameters like this?

```
$result = $this->find('all', array('order' =>'id'));
```

Because my doubt is: is useful to cache query with parameter or not? Is a good way to make more efficient the speed of the site?

Comment: What do you mean? I cannot follow. If you got "several" aliases you need to inlude the alias in the key. otherwise they would all get each others (wrong) cache result!

Comment: I want to know if is useful and efficient t cache query with parameters that i pass or not. Or if i have to cache only the query standard like select all from a table

Comment: Cache what you need to: there’s no catch-all answer. It entirely depends on your application, what queries are executed frequently, and whether there’s any variance in the data.